# how to play DivX videos using Vitamio?

Tags: android, avi, divx

Simple AVI videos seem to play fine in videoView, as well as I can get thumbnails from them by

```
        Bitmap bMap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(s, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND);
        ivPic.setImageBitmap(bMap);
```

Yet DivX avi videos won't play and won't give me a thumbnail.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:
I found this vitamio library and nevertheless I had put its JAR file into my app, when I'm trying to play the divx file, it pops a dialog, offering to download some plugin... is there a way round it?**

Comment: You can edit/remove the dialog, but the library requries the plugin inorder to work.

Comment: You changed the question after my answer... Don't do that. Ask a new one instead.

Answer (score 2):

Android doesn't support DivX videos. See this link for an overview of supported media formats: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

**Edit:** This is an answer to the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11815604/revisions), which was about playing DivX in a `VideoView` and didn't include anything about "Vitamio".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Vitamio library for displaying video etc, then first of all download Vitamio Library from here [Free download Vitamio Library](http://unblockanything.com/browse.php?u=kwhmI3OGaDgEb3JuWtCATO%2be0rejRWf5Lc3MKuWhDlLpdg==&b=29&f=norefer).
then include both "ZI" and "InitActivtiy" (which is inside the Vitamio lib) Library in your current project (right click project-->include library-->), then write this line of code

```
 if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
```

after Oncreate Method() like in my project.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (!io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this)) //it will check the include library of Vitamio
        return;
```

after that put this line of code in Androidmanifest.xml file

```
  <!-- (((((( Vitamio Library including in manifest file )))))) -->
   <activity android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity" 
       android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden"
       android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Now its a time to display your video using VideoView etc.